# How to implement action in didSelectRowAtIndexPath of UITableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

On my view, I used to have few buttons and each button had an action associated with it.

```
    UIButton *testButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120,300,90,90)];
    [testButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [testButton addTarget:self.view action:@selector(gotoProd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [testButton addt
    [scrollView testButton];
```

But now I am trying to replace all those buttons with the tableview with rows. I was able to populate the rows and I know one needs to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath for handling on select event of the cell. But how can I implement action:@selector(gotoProd:) in tableviews ?? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straight-forward way would look like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [self doRow0Action];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self doRow1Action];
            break;
        // etc...

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

If you wanted to instead, you could initialize an array with SEL types:

```
[actionArray addObject:@selector(doRowNAction)];
```

then access it like this:

```
[self performSelector:[actionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withObject:nil];
```

Comment: This answer also helps if you're wrapping all Cell data in an NSDictionary, defining selector names with NSString. You can use 
    [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([cellData objectForKey:@"cell_selector"])]; in didSelectRow to perform your action.

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
[self gotoProd:indexPath.row];
```

from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

and

```
 - (void)gotoProd:(int)rowSelected {
      //Check row index here and do it accordingly
 }
```